# ADO.Net with Oracle

Tags: c#, oracle, ado.net

I am developing an application with C# but we are told to use Oracle references despite od SQL  ones, where ever on internet and youtube i go,i find SQL tutorials, i have some simple questions if someone can help me please...

Can anyone clear the use of all listed below.

1. OracleConnection
2. OracleCommand with CommandText and ExecuteReader
3. OracleDataAdapter
4. DataTable
5. OracleCommandBuilder
6. OracleReader

Can anyone give a brief description what these classes do and how are they used in which order and what are their kind of approach (connected/disconnected)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a very big topic for someone to cover in a post, but basically you need to read about ADO.Net generally. There's nothing different about the Oracle stuff...

The data readers are only useful when you are merely wanting to read the information - but when that is the case, they are faster than datatables - USUALLY. The reader keeps it's connection open throughout the read through though - and in some circumstances you might be better to simply suck everything through an Adapter into a DataTable first, close the connection, and play with it from there.

It depends what you're doing - how much data etc...

DataReader is always connected - DataTable can (and frequently is) disconnected.

Hope that gets you started...

Comment: i would just like to get a little hint of all listed what those things do, as i already have the code but do not know what that things do...

Comment: Hi Rushabh - I understand that, but what I am saying is that there really isn't a shortcut to simply researching ADO.Net. Have you tried watching a few youtube videos on the subject? I found those helpful when I started out...

Comment: Can you provide the links please, i found a lot of videos, confused for the best...!!

Answer (score 2):

You should use `Oracle.DataAccess` from Oracle instead of `System.Data.Oracle` from Microsoft - this provider is deprecated and should not be used in new projects anymore: [Oracle and ADO.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/77d8yct7%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

From my experience theres a huge difference between Oracle.DataAccess and System.Data.Oracle.

First - the Oracle ODP .net (ADO.NET implementation) has all the specific classes for Oracle (such as OracleClob etc..)

Second - I had less bugs and weird issues with dates and type conversions in general.

The usage of the ODP.net and the System.Data.Oracle is almost the same - the main difference is that for Oracle implementation (of the unmanaged driver) you have to call to dispose for each and every method.

In general - your code would look like that:

```
OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(connStr);
OracleCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
cmd.Connection = con;
cmd.CommandText = "select * from user_tables";

OracleDataReader odr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
while (odr.Read())
{
   string sz = odr.GetString(0);
}
odr.Close();
odr.Dispose();

cmd.Dispose();
con.Close();
con.Dispose();
```

As I write to everybody - I write code from memory, so if I have syntax mistakes - fix them, the idea should still be the same.

Now for using DataTables you would use OracleDataAdapter (which contains/returns the objects you listed), but I will not explain about them - since I don't want you to use them.
They have many issues with parallel access and I feel working with the bare ADO is much better.